# Dexiejs db.version().stores() does not initialize tables in my React app but works fine in Codesandbox and StackBlitz

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, indexeddb, dexie

I'm attempting to initialize an indexedDB with Dexie and it appears to work w/o/e in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dexie-one-to-many-6fevqk?file=db.ts) and [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-butterfly-d646s?file=/src/index.ts) but not when I port the code to my app ([repo](https://github.com/hyetigran/AWS-Exam-Client)). (DB related code is in the exam-history branch).

On initial render, triggers `TypeError: Cannot read property 'mapToClass' of undefined`
When inspecting db on debugger in StackBlitz, it shows exams, answers, questions as Table$$1. However, locally it is coming up undefined.

db.ts

```
import Dexie from "dexie";

import { Answer, Question, Exam } from "./model";

class ExamDatabase extends Dexie {
  public exams: Dexie.Table<Exam, number>;
  public questions: Dexie.Table<Question, number>;
  public answers: Dexie.Table<Answer, number>;

  constructor() {
    super("ExamDatabase");
    const db = this;
    db.version(1).stores({
      exams:
        "&gid, examNumber, examType, correct, currentQuestion, time, isPaused",
      questions: "&gid, examId, question, explanation, isMultipleChoice",
      answers: "&gid, questionId, type, choice, isSelected, isCorrect"
    });

    debugger
    db.exams.mapToClass(Exam);
    db.questions.mapToClass(Question);
    db.answers.mapToClass(Answer);
  }
}

export const db = new ExamDatabase();
```

model.ts

```
import cuid from "cuid";

export abstract class AbstractEntity {
  constructor(public gid?: string) {
    gid ? (this.gid = gid) : (this.gid = cuid());
  }
  equals(e1: AbstractEntity, e2: AbstractEntity) {
    return e1.gid === e2.gid;
  }
}

export class Answer extends AbstractEntity {
  constructor(
    public questionId: string,
    public choice: string,
    public isSelected: boolean,
    public isCorrect: boolean,
    gid?: string
  ) {
    super(gid);
  }
}

export class Question extends AbstractEntity {
  answers: Answer[];

  constructor(
    public examId: string,
    public question: string,
    public explanation: string,
    public isMultipleChoice: boolean,
    gid?: string
  ) {
    super(gid);

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      answers: { value: [], enumerable: false, writable: true },
    });
  }
}

export class Exam extends AbstractEntity {
  questions: Question[];

  constructor(
    public examNumber: string,
    public examType: string,
    public correct: number,
    public currentQuestion: number,
    public time: string,
    public isPaused: boolean,
    gid?: string
  ) {
    super(gid);

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      questions: { value: [], enumerable: false, writable: true },
    });
  }
}
```

logging 'db'
[image]

logging 'db' in StackBlitz
[image]

Comment: Could you provide more details about your local setup? Are you using SSR, for example?

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski Using CSR with frontend built with js/react

Comment: Are you sure that Dexie versions are the same?

Comment: Using Dexie version 3.0.2 in both places

Comment: Can you try removing `public exams: Dexie.Table<Exam, number>;
  public questions: Dexie.Table<Question, number>;
  public answers: Dexie.Table<Answer, number>;`?

Comment: Are TypeScript versions the same in both places?

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski Using Typescript 3.9.7 in app and in StackBlitz only dependency is tslib 1.11.1

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski removing the public fields makes or setting type to any makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the fix was to replace mapToClass with table method in the db constructor.

```
db.exams = db.table("exams");
db.questions = db.table("questions");
db.answers = db.table("answers");
```

However, I would still appreciate if someone could explain why mapToClass works in codesandbox env and not in local server.

Dexie version 3.0.2

Typescript version 3.9.7

And tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```